# Jquery Inter-Frame Communication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frame

I have `main_page.htm` as

```
<frameset rows="30,*" frameborder=0 border=0>
       <frame name="top_frame" src="top.htm">
       <frame name="bottom_frame" src="bottom.htm">
</frameset>
```

The code in bottom.htm is :

```
<div id="BottomFrameTest">Hi There!</div>
```

Now How can I change the text in the above from `top.htm` which is in top_frame

The code in top.htm is :

```
<script>
   function ChnageDivText()
   {
      $("#BottomFrameTest").html("Hello World. This text is changed");
   }
</script>
<body>
   <input type="button" value="Change Text" onclick="ChnageDivText()" />
</body>
```

Above code obviously doesn't work. How can I communicate with `bottom_frame` from `top_frame` ?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing all your frames come from the same domain you can use

```
 parent.bottom_frame.getElementById("BottomFrameTest").innerHTML = "Hello World. This text is changed";
```

And of course, if you really want to use jquery, you can do

```
 $(parent.bottom_frame).find("#BottomFrameTest").html("Hello World. This text is changed");
```

Comment: In the second code snippet, you forgot the pound sign in front of the ID. (`BottomFrameTest` -> `#BottomFrameTest`)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this actually you are trying to update an element for other frame so you are trying crossframe jquery operations

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function ChnageDivText()
       {
          $(parent.BottomFrameTest.document).contents().find(‘#TextBox1′).val(‘Hello World. This text is changed’);
       }

});
```

i've used textbox for example you can set the id of your desired element in your find method.
you can find it in more depth [here](http://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2009/07/30/cross-frame-access-with-jquery/).

if `$.contents()` is new for you, you can find it documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) .

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/contents/#example-1) is a somewhat similar example from jquery docs.

Hope that all will help you.